# ubuntu 12.04 boot screen remained like 10.04

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, boot, upgrade

The system is upgraded from ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04,yet the boot screen is same.
It takes longer to boot than before and system checks disk drives for error on every startup.

can I get any help on it?????

Answer (score 0):

Run: `sudo tune2fs -c 30 /dev/hda1`

Replace `/dev/hda1` with the filesystems that it's checking every boot.

Comment: It has already been set to 30,but still it's checking every time instead of after 30 restarts.Is there any other alternative????

Comment: you wouldnt happen to have a /forcefsck file, would you?